# React components inside Angular 1.4 application

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I have an angular application built using gulp. I want to use React components inside it for different functionalities. Angular application is loading js through script tags and React app have its own store containers etc. and is using React 16.

How can I import my components etc inside angular.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `React Component` with Angular `Directive` or use can use it inside
 `$onInit` in `angular`

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    displayName:'Hello World',
    render:function(){
        return React.DOM.div(Test, "Hello, ",this.props.value1);
    }
});

$scope.name = 'World!';

app.directive('hello', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            name:'='
        },
        link:function(scope, el, attrs){
            scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue){
                var MyComponent = React.createFactory(HelloWorld);
                ReactDOM.render(
                    MyComponent({value1:newValue}),
                    el[0]
                );
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Any existing AngularJS/React adapter like [`react2angular`](https://github.com/coatue-oss/react2angular) can be used.

All these adapters do is `ReactDOM.render` in `$onInit` hook and `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` in `$onDestroy`.

Comment: Don't think it works with Angular 1.4 given it relies on a `.component` method which is not available in Angular 1.4

Comment: Thanks for commented downvote. I listed react2angular as example implementation, https://github.com/coatue-oss/react2angular/blob/master/index.tsx . In case it doesn't suit a user (the OP is forced to use 1.4 but other viewers may not), a user can use the same approach for custom implementation. And btw, `component` can be polyfilled in 1.4 with https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-component